# merge collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection of objects with repeated value. Lets say that the object is:

```
public InvoiceCompany
{
    public decimal InvoiceValue { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

and I have multiple invoices for each company in List collection. How can I merge objects in the collection, distinct Companies and add their InvoiceValues at the same time? I would like to do it using Linq!

Comment: What's the final output you desire? anonymous type? which properties will it contain?

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, please post the code and what problems it has. If not: why not?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input and expected output please?

Comment: I have: (15.5-A, 4.5-A, 15.5-B, 4.5-B). Would like to get (20-A, 20-B). Not started writing code yet since don't know how to approach it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `GroupBy`:

```
var list = new List<InvoiceCompany>(); //your collection of invoices
var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.Company)
                  .Select(g => new InvoiceCompany { Company = g.Key, InvoiceValue = g.Sum(x => x.InvoiceValue) });
```

Comment: I think the `Select` should look like this: `Select(g = new InvoiceCompany { Company = g.Key, InvoiceValue = g.Sum(x => x.InvoiceValue) })`. Reason: The OP states: *"add their InvoiceValues at the same time"*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a group by statement.

```
List<InvoiceCompany> li = new List<InvoiceCompany>(){
     new InvoiceCompany { Company = "a", InvoiceValue = 1 },
     new InvoiceCompany { Company = "a", InvoiceValue = 2 },
     new InvoiceCompany { Company = "b", InvoiceValue = 1 },
     new InvoiceCompany { Company = "b", InvoiceValue = 2 }
};

var v = from a in li
        group a.InvoiceValue by a.Company into b
        select new { Company = b.Key, Invoices = b.ToList().Sum() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to group your InvoiceValue by the Company and calculate the sum:

```
var v =
from l in list
group l.InvoiceValue by l.Company
into g
select new InvoiceCompany()
{
    Company = g.Key,
    InvoiceValue = g.Sum()
};
```